# I am trying to plot a bar graph, but I am constantly getting this error

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

My code:

```
Dict = {'b':1 , 'n':1, '-':20, '\xa0':5}
x = list(Dict.keys())
y = list(Dict.values())
fig = plt.figure(figsiz = (10,5))

plt.bar(x,y,width = 0.5, color = 'maroon')
```

Error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: I get no error. Please post the full traceback. What line is the error occurring at?

Comment: plt.bar(x,y,width = 0.5,color = 'maroon')

Comment: It seems that one of your values is a string when it should be a float. Either x or y is probably a string. try casting them both to a float like so:
plt.bar(float(x), float(y), width=0.5, color='maroon')

Comment: This is a `matplotlib` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed). Plus, please do not post any code that comes *after* the error, as it is irrelevant to the issue and it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib is telling you that it doesn't know how to plot your `Dict.keys()` on the X axis. You'll need to plot your bars with numeric values for the X axis and then you can assign the `Dict.keys()` to the bars as tick labels. You'll need to adjust the plot scale and/or your data dictionary to get the data to display properly. The following code shows how to get the data to plot and how to assign the tick labels (but does not make any other adjustments).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dict = {u'b':1 , u'n':1, u'-':20, u'\xa0':5}

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 1, 20, 5]
labels = [u'b', u'n', u'-', u'\xa0']  # Note that '\xa0' is a non-breaking space

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,5))
plt.bar(x,y,width = 0.5, color = 'maroon')
plt.xticks(x, labels)

plt.show()
```

Note: depending on your Python version, you can't guarantee in what order the dictionary keys and values will be delivered. I've updated this answer to hard-code the data, to make the answer to your original question more obvious.